# Excel 2016 - dynamically load table data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

Need advice on the best way to create a table as shown in the [attached diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nucvf.png).
[image]
The dataset of this table is "relational". As in (with reference to attached screenshot), department has one or many employees and the table shows the stats/info about these employees. Therefore the rowspans used in the values in the first column should be equal to the relevant number of employees.

Another issue is that due to the data in this table being used to calculate values on another sheet and drawing charts, it needs to be "limited" accordingly. As in when calculating average basic salary of each department it needs to be limited as such:
Basic salary of department 1 = AVERAGE(D3:D5) // because 3 employees
Basic salary of department 2 = AVERAGE(D6:D7) // because 2 employees

These need to be dynamic as ultimately the data will be populated by a web service and the values should be calculated and data plotted accordingly.

I hope the question is clear. I do not have much experience in Excel therefore I am unsure if I detailed my requirement clearly. Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: *the rowspans used in the values in the first column should be equal to the relevant number of employees* Rowspan (any span) cannot be set by formula. Only by VBA or "by hands". For VBA solution the joining criteria suitable for auto-check must exist. And you must remember that the value of spanned range is referenced to its left-upper cell only.

Comment: Could you please [Edit] your post & add sample data from both Tables also you have used word Relational then what are key fields in both Tables !!

Comment: @Akina _For VBA solution the joining criteria suitable for auto-check must exist_ could you please explain this a bit more? Thanks

Comment: @RajeshS Apologies if I misused the word _relational._ What I actually meant was the data is somewhat "grouped", as in all employees belong to a department. There is only one table

Comment: *explain this a bit more?* VBA code must find some point where it must stop current span and start another, where is a border between departments. Your current sample have no this.

Comment: @Akina I get it.. How is this border usually defined?

Comment: I don't know. That is YOUR data, so that's YOU who knows...

Comment: Oh I get it.. I thought you were referring to a border such as a UI element. Currently the border in my data set is the different departments (department1, department2 etc) is this sufficient?